# Add column elements to a Dataframe Scala Spark

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have two dataframes, and I want to add one to all row of the other one.
My dataframes are like:

```
id | name | rate 
 1 |   a  |  3
 1 |   b  |  4
 1 |   c  |  1
 2 |   a  |  2
 2 |   d  |  4
```

```
name 

a
b
c
d
e
```

And I want a result like this:

```
id | name | rate 
 1 |   a  |  3
 1 |   b  |  4
 1 |   c  |  1
 1 |   d  | null
 1 |   e  | null
 2 |   a  |  2
 2 |   b  | null
 2 |   c  | null
 2 |   d  |  4
 2 |   e  | null
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it's more than a simple join.

```
val df = df1.select("id").distinct().crossJoin(df2).join(
    df1,
    Seq("name", "id"),
    "left"
).orderBy("id", "name")

df.show
+----+---+----+
|name| id|rate|
+----+---+----+
|   a|  1|   3|
|   b|  1|   4|
|   c|  1|   1|
|   d|  1|null|
|   e|  1|null|
|   a|  2|   2|
|   b|  2|null|
|   c|  2|null|
|   d|  2|   4|
|   e|  2|null|
+----+---+----+
```